# Is there a way to convert codesys v2.3 project to codesys v3.5?

Tags: plc, codesys, iec61131-3, wago

I have a codesys project of version V2.3 and I want to open it in V3.5. Is there any way where i can convert my V2.3 Project and Open it in V3.5?

Answer (score 1):

Codesys provides [CODESYS V2.3 Converter](https://store.codesys.com/en/codesys-v2-3-converter.html) tool for this.

Install the package in the Codesys 3.5 and then open the old project and the conversion will start.

[image]

However, because of the different libraries and structure, some manual adjustments are sometimes necessary.

Comment: Yes, found that there is a codesys V2.3 to 3.5 converter available on (https://store.codesys.com/de/codesys-v2-3-converter.html). However it has to be noted that it only works with the codesys 32 bit version.

Comment: Have you tried installing the 32-bit IDE, converting the project and then opening it in the 64-bit version?

Comment: 32-bit IDE meaning codesys v3.5 32 bit? I had installed codesys v3.5 32 bit and tried converting the project, however the libraries are to be reinstalled based on the manufacturer of the PLC. But i haven't tried loading the project in 64 bit version.